# How do I turn on Quasar dark mode for a Vue3 App on all components?

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

I have the following...

```
import { Quasar, Dark } from "quasar";
...
Dark.set(true);

async function startApp() {
    const app = createApp(App);
    ...
    app.use(Quasar, {
        plugins: {}, // import Quasar plugins and add here
    });
    app.mount("#app");
}

startApp().then(()=>{
    console.log("SPA started");
})
```

But it isn't setting the project to dark. What am I missing? I am using the `<script setup>` syntax for my component so whatever solution would need to work with that setup.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass `dark: true` as an option of Quasar's plugin during registration.

```js
app.use(Quasar, {
  plugins: {}, // import Quasar plugins and add here  
  config: {
    dark: true,
  },
});
```